# Number of subgroups of a given index of a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, free-groups

Given $n,d\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, how many subgroups of index $d$ does the free group of
rank $n$ have?

In case $n=1$ the question is trivial, and in case $n=2, d=2$ there are 3 such subgroups.
I think I have got a algorithm to solve case $d=2$ for arbitrary $n$.
But the general case seems very difficult. For example in case $n=2$ and $d$ a
prime number, I don't know how to proceed.

That's my question. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Google subgroup growth.

Comment: A recursive formula was obtained by Marshall Hall: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=28836

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This calculation was performed by [Marshall Hall Jr](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=hall%2C%20m*&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=181&mx-pid=28836). Let $N(d,n)$ be the number of subgroups of index $d$ in the free group of rank $n$.  Then

$N(d,n)=d(d!)^{n-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{d-1}((d-i)!)^{n-1}N(i,n)$.

One can prove this inductively by analysing permutation groups as in abx's answer, or alternatively by thinking about covering spaces of graphs---see the answers to [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9705/finding-subgroups-of-a-free-group-with-a-specific-index) for a few more details.

Comment: A more elegant way of stating Hall's result is $\log\sum_{d\geq 0} d!^{n-1} x^d= \sum_{d\geq 1}N(d,n)\frac{x^d}{d}$. See *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, Exercise 5.13 for this and related results.

Comment: That's very nice!

Answer (score 7):

This is a very incomplete answer. The case $d=2$ is particular because a subgroup of index 2 is normal. In this case subgroups of order 2 of $F_n$ correspond bijectively to surjective homomorphisms $F_n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$. Such a map factors through the abelian quotient $\mathbb{Z}^n$, thus there are $2^n-1$ subgroups of index 2 of $F_n$.

In general subgroups of index $d$ of $F_n$ correspond to $n$-uples of permutations $(\sigma _1,\ldots ,\sigma _n)$ in $\mathfrak{S}_d$ such that the subgroup they generate acts transitively on $[1,d]$, up to conjugacy by $\mathfrak{S}_{d-1}$. They also correspond to $d$-sheeted covering of the sphere branched along $\{1,\ldots ,d\} $. This is reminiscent of [Hurwitz numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELSV_formula) though it does not seem to be directly related.